# Parameter values are not being sent from script to blend tree (Unity 2020)

Tags: unity-game-engine

(Parameter values are not being sent from script to blend tree resulting in not following animation with movement.) I have animations set up in a blend tree that has a 1d type blend tree. I have it set to custom thresholds with an idle animation as the base state then the blend tree has three motions: a strafe left, right, and a walk forward. When I move forward the player does not do the animations told in the tree and I am almost certain it is the script.

I am also using Unity 1212.1.2f1 and for my scripts I have been using Microsoft Visual Studio if it matters.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public float rotationSpeed = 75.0f;

    public Animator anim;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()

    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)

        {
            velocity.y = -2f;

        }
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if ((Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) && isGrounded)
        {

            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);

        }

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);


        
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Vertical", Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        }

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first i think you could try to make a new var :

```
private Rigidbody2D rg;
```

then add this in Start ()

```
    rg = Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

and Update () with this

```
anim.SetFloat("Vertical", rg.velocity.x);
anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", rgvelocity.x);
```

and sure made 2 Vertical and Horizontal in Animator parameters

Comment: This was a good idea except It still did not fix the issue. I am not using a Rigidbody on my player because the script determines my values so there is no need for it and adding a Rigidbody actually made it worse. Once adding a Rigidbody it removed my current animation when moving forward. Any other ideas?

Comment: maybe you could try this because we in Update method too :
anim.SetFloat("Vertical", x);
anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", z);